# PIC18F4620 ADC Conversion

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, c

I'm in need of help in understanding how to code ADC conversions for the PIC18F4620.
If someone could provide an example code with comments that would be great.  Also if someone can explain to me how to do ADC polling. I have tried the code below:

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    int sensor;
    ADCON1 = 0b00000111; //VSS,VDD ref. AN0 through AN7 analog only 
    ADCON0 = 0x0100; //clear ADCON0 to select channel 0 (AN0) 
    ADCON2 = 0b00001000; //ADCON2 setup: Left justified, Tacq=2Tad, Tad=2*Tosc (or Fosc/2) 
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 0x01; //Enable A/D module 
    while(1) { 
        ADCON0bits.GO_DONE = 1; //Start A/D Conversion 
        while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE != 0); //Loop here until A/D conversion completes 
        { 
            sensor = ADRESH; 
        } 
     } 
}
```

But the values give back a constant 0.

Comment: i have tried the code below: 
int main(void)
{
    int sensor;
 ADCON1 = 0b00000111;//VSS,VDD ref. AN0 through AN7 analog only
 ADCON0 = 0x0100;//clear ADCON0 to select channel 0 (AN0)
 ADCON2 = 0b00001000;//ADCON2 setup: Left justified, Tacq=2Tad, Tad=2*Tosc (or Fosc/2)
 ADCON0bits.ADON = 0x01;//Enable A/D module

        while(1)
 {
  ADCON0bits.GO_DONE = 1;//Start A/D Conversion

  while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE != 0);//Loop here until A/D conversion completes
                {
                    sensor = ADRESH;
                }
        }

}
But the values give back a constant 0.

Comment: I've just put that code in the question, I didn't check the setup carefully but you probably want something like `sensor = (ADRESH << 8) | ADRESL` to get the complete reading rather than just the MSB.

Answer (score 2):

With some searching around I found [this project](http://robosumo.wordpress.com/pic18f4620/), which has a [code example](http://robosumo.wordpress.com/pic18f4620/#template_code) which uses the ADC. Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <delays.h>

#pragma config OSC=INTIO67,MCLRE=OFF,WDT=OFF,LVP=OFF

// Function prototypes
void setup(void);
unsigned int read_analog_channel(unsigned int);

void main(void) {
    setup(); // Configure the PIC
    unsigned int analog_val;
    while(1) {
        analog_val = read_analog_channel(0);
        LATDbits.LATD1 = 1;  // Set RD1 high
        Delay1KTCYx(analog_val);
        LATDbits.LATD1 = 0;  // Set RD1 low
        Delay1KTCYx(1000);   // 500ms delay
    }
}

void setup(void) {
    // Set clock frequency (section 2 of the PIC18F4620 Data Sheet)
    // Set Fosc = 8MHz, which gives Tcy = 0.5us
    OSCCON = 0b01110000;

    // Set up ADC (section 19 of the PIC18F4620 Data Sheet)
    // Enable AN0-7 as analog inputs
    ADCON1 = 0b00000111;
    // Left justified result, manual acquisition time,
    // AD clock source = 8 x Tosc
    ADCON2 = 0b00000001;
}

// Read voltage from the specified channel.
// This function takes approximately 35us.
unsigned int read_analog_channel(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int voltage;

    ADCON0 = n << 2;
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
    Delay10TCYx(3); // 15us charging time
    ADCON0bits.GO = 1;
    while (ADCON0bits.GO); // Await result (11us approx)

    // Return the result (a number between 0 and 1023)
    voltage = ADRESH;
    voltage = (voltage << 2) + (ADRESL >> 6);
    return voltage;
}
```

---

**However, it would be better to have a look why your code didn't work.** You give the same value to `ADCON1`. `ADCON2` is different, but that only changes the clock rates and things like this, nothing that shouldn't work.

Then for `ADCON0`, the example I give is slightly different because it allows you to use one function for different analogue channels, so `ADCON0` is changed in `read_analog_channel()`. One minor note on your code: when you give `ADCON0` the value `0x0100`, you give it a value which is higher than a byte! Because of the `x`, the literal is read as hexadecimal. You're trying to put *two* bytes in one register. However, that means just the lower byte is selected, `0x00`, so the register is cleared. But it would be good to change this line into `ADCON0 = 0b00000001` or something like this. The last bit needs to be set because it enables the module (what you do with `ADCON0bits.ADON = 0x01`). See the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39626b.pdf) for more information (p. 223).

But now your while loop:

```
while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE != 0); //Loop here until A/D conversion completes 
{ 
    sensor = ADRESH; 
}
```

This code is correct, but confusing. The accolades (`{` and `}`) make it look like you're looping through that part of the code, while in fact you're doing this:

```
while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE != 0); //Loop here until A/D conversion completes 
sensor = ADRESH;
```

Or this, if it helps you to understand:

```
while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE != 0) //Loop here until A/D conversion completes 
{
} 
sensor = ADRESH;
```

Because of the semicolon (`;`) you put after the first line.

Then the last thing is the way you read out the result from `ADRESH`. That's not where the result is loaded, it's only part of the result (you can read more about this in the datasheet). The full result is stored in the register pair `ADRESH:ADRESL`. So to get the result, we need to do a little arithmetic:

```
sensor = ADRESH;
sensor = (sensor << 2) + (ADRESL >> 6);
```

**Long story short**, there are some details in your code that are not so neat, and here is your code in a neater version:

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    word sensor; // Should be a word (16 bits), not an int (32 bits)
    ADCON1 = 0b00000111; //VSS,VDD ref. AN0 through AN7 analog only 
    ADCON0 = 0b00000001; //select channel 0 (AN0), enable module
    ADCON2 = 0b00001000; //ADCON2 setup: Left justified, Tacq=2Tad, Tad=2*Tosc (or Fosc/2) 
    while(1) 
    { 
        ADCON0bits.GO_DONE = 1; //Start A/D Conversion 
        while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE != 0); //Loop here until A/D conversion completes 
        sensor = ADRESH;
        sensor = (sensor << 2) + (ADRESL >> 6);
        // Now here you should do something with the value of sensor; 
        // send it over USART, put it on an LCD or something like that.
    } 
}
```

---

**Then about ADC polling:** this is basically just the term for periodically checking the ADC. You're doing this already, because the polling is in a while loop: the sensor is already checked all the time.

Sometimes you only want to check it every now and then, and you don't need to use the full speed of the PIC. In that case, you just add a delay in the loop.